# Axiom of choice equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A  family of sets F is called interesting if $$\exists n \in \omega \forall X (X \in F \iff \forall Y (Y \subseteq X \land |Y| \leq n \implies Y \in F)$$
I have the following **lemma**:

If F is an **interesting**  family and $x\in F$, then there is a maximal $Y \in F$ (according to the $\subseteq$), such that $X \subseteq Y$.

I need to shouw that this lemma is **equivalent to the axiom of choice**.

**My attempt:**

I have noticed that this lemma has a tight connection with [Teichmüller–Tukey lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller%E2%80%93Tukey_lemma).(which is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice)

It's easy to see that **every interesting Family is of finite character**.
So the given lemma is a bit "stronger" than the **Teichmüller–Tukey lemma**.
But can I conclude that lemma and the AC are equivalent from that? Probably just the first direction (Lemma $\implies$ Axiom of Choice). But I can't figure the other direction.
Any tips?

PS: I think **the question was wrongfully closed**: The given solution has nothing to do with the task.

Comment: Since your lemma is at least as strong as the Tukey–Teichmüller lemma, it implies choice, so we need only prove the converse. You probably just need to slightly modify [the proof of the TTL from AC](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tukey-Teichmüller_Lemma#Proof)

Comment: I think you've got an implication backward. Since every interesting family is of finite character, your lemma follows immediately from the Teichmüller-Tukey Lemma (and therefore from AC). The nontrivial part of your problem is to show that your lemma implies AC. For that, it helps to note a family of partial choice functions is interesting, with $n=2$.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, because the last clause was wrong and it was too late to edit, and I replaced it with a new comment that I hope is helpful.